# why does map not return a new array but returns strings separated by commas

Tags: javascript

Answers.js

```
const { ups , answer, displayName, photoURL, userid, increment, answerid, index, answers} = props;

  const upvote = () => {
  const newarr = answers.map(item => item.voters);
  console.log("new arr is " + newarr)
```

//console logs strings seperated by commas not an array of voters

```
  authUser &&  increment(index);
}
```

app.js

```
increment = (index) => {
  let answers = this.state.answers.slice();
  ++answers[index].ups;
  answers[index].voters.push(answers[index].userid)
  this.setState({answers})
}
```

Here is what the answer looks like

```
makeAnswer() {
  const answer = ({ answer:this.state.answer, belongsTo:this.state.openedPost, ups:0, isAccepted: false, id:this.getPostId(), userid:this.context.authUser.uid, displayName:this.context.authUser.displayName, photoURL:this.context.authUser.photoURL, date:Date.now(), voters:[] })
  return answer;
}
```

Comment: You're using string concatenation in your console.log, newArr is converted to a string thus.

Comment: @Axnyff that happened even when i did `console.log('new arr is ${newarr}')`

Comment: The is still converting newArr to string. Just console.log (newArr) and it will work

Comment: @Axnyff ok im aware that works but the reason I added variable name before is because when i was doing debugging and logging a lot of things it makes things more clear. Guess it does not work with javascript.

Comment: `console.log('new arr is', newArr)̀` As long as you don't do concatenation it will work like you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `newarr` is converted to a string due to concatenation; do this instead:

```
console.log("new arr is", newarr)
```